# SharePoint 2010: what's the recommended way to store news?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

To store news for a news site, what's a good recommendation?

So far, I'm opting for creating a News Site, mainly because: I get some web parts for free (RSS, "week in pictures"), workflows in place and authoring experience in SharePoint seeems reasonable.

On the other hand, I see for example that, by just creating a Document Library, I can store Word documents based on "Newsletter" template and saved as web page and they look great, and the authoring experience in Word is better than that on SharePoint.

And what about just creating a blog site!

Anyway, what would people do? Am I missing a crucial factor here for one or the other? What's a good trade-off here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the best option would be to

- Create a new News Site
- Create a custom content type having properties like Region (Choice), Category (Choice),  Show on homepage (Boolean) , Summary (Note) etc.
- Create a custom page layout attached to above content type. Give it a look and feel you want your news article to look like.
- Attach the page layout as default content type to Pages Library of News site.

The advantages of this approach is that you can use CQWP web part on the home page to show latest 5 articles. You can also show a one liner or a picture if you also make it a property in custom content type.

By Storing News in a word document, you are not really using SharePoint as Publishing Environment but only as repository. Choice is yours.

Answer (score 2):

D. All of the above

SharePoint gives you a lot of options because there is no one sized solution that works for everyone. The flexibility of options is not to overwhelm you with choices, but rather to allow you to focus on your process, either how it exists now or how you want it to be, and then select the option that best fits your process.

My company's intranet is a team site and news is placed into an Announcements list. We do not need any flashy. The plain text just needs to be communicated to the employees. On the other hand, our public internet site is a publishing site, which gives our news pages a more finished touch in terms of styling and images. It also allows us to take advantage of scheduling, content roll-up, friendly URLs along with the security of locking down the view forms. Authoring and publishing such a page is more involved than the Announcements list, but each option perfectly fits what we want to accomplish in each environment.

Without knowing more about your needs or process, based only on your highlighting Word as the preferred authoring tool, I would recommend a Blog. It is not as fully featured as a publishing site, but there is some overlap. And posts can be authored in Word.

In the end, if you can list what you want to accomplish, how you want to accomplish it, and pick the closest option (News Site, Team Site, Publishing Site, Blog, Wiki, etc), then you will have made the correct choice.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use news publishing sites, for what you said and page editing features.

It also allows you to set scheduled go-live and un-publish dates which is kind of critical for news items.